# How to concatenate 'str' and 'list' objects in python?

Tags: loops, python-2.7, for-loop

I'm writing a python program.

```
fns = [10,20,30,40,45,49,51,54,57]
file1="/run/media/john/Seagate Expansion Drive/cosmo-sim_9/RD00"
file2="/RedshiftOutput00"
for i, fn in enumerate(fns):
    fn=file1+fns+file2+fns # parameter file to load
    print fn
```

I am getting the following error.

> fn=file1+fns+file2+fns # parameter file to load
>
> TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'list' objects

How to get rid of this? I want to load different files according to the numbers in the list.

Thank You.

Comment: What's the expected output?

Comment: It should be `fn` not `fns`, and use `str.format` rather than `+`

Comment: @jonrsharpe thanks... it was my mistake                                                                                              `for i, fn in enumerate(fns):
    fn_1=file1+fn+file2+fn 
    print fn_1`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.join()` to convert from a list to a string:

```
>>> fns = [10,20,30,40,45,49,51,54,57]
>>> ''.join([str(item) for item in fns])
'102030404549515457'
>>>
```

Here is your edited code:

```
fns = [10,20,30,40,45,49,51,54,57]
file1="/run/media/john/Seagate Expansion Drive/cosmo-sim_9/RD00"
file2="/RedshiftOutput00"
for i, fn in enumerate(fns):
    temp = ''.join([str(item) for item in fns])
    print file1+temp+file2+temp # parameter file to load
```

Comment: I want to take each number at a time. That is first 10 then 20 and so on.